# Database isn't being updated

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I've just started using Entity, and so far, it's made my life infinitely easier. However, when I try to update a row, this is where I run into issues. Googling brought me to the `Attach()`, to which I've tried:

```
public void Update()
{
    using (var context = new HDDCContainer())
    {
        context.Projects.Attach(this);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

This is a method that is in my Project class.

However, after querying my database, I find that it, in fact, did not update. I get no errors or exceptions from this. When I step through, I can see the changes to the project that I made.

Comment: Let's have the complete code you use to save an entity...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to tell Entity frame work that the state of the object that you have just attached have been changed in comparison with the value that is in the database, you simply modify the state of the entry as the following:

```
            db.Favorites.Attach(favorite);
            var ent = db.Entry(favorite);
            ent.State = EntityState.Modified;   
            db.SaveChanges();
```

Have ago at it and let me know

Comment: Good to hear that ,No problem

Answer (score 2):

You must make changes to the entity **after** it is attached.

For example

```
context.Projects.Attach(project);

project.Name = "New Funky Name";

context.SaveChanges();
```

If the entity is being modified outside you save/update method as per your example, then you may need to flag the state manually.

```
context.Projects.Attach(project);
DbEntityEntry entry = context.Entry(day);       // Gets the entity Entry instance
entry.Property("Name").IsModified = true;       // Individual property modified
entry.State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified; // or Entire object modified
```